# Delete Project in Google Spreadsheet Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

There are two project created by previous owners and I want to get rid of them. If I try to delete the file an error message occurs:
'The only open file can not be deleted.'
 [delete_file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6LKk.jpg)
 [delete_file_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hx2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Projects initialise with a single file (code.gs). You cannot have an 'empty' project - you must have at least one file present. Delete the text contents of 'Kopie von code.gs' in your project, rename it and start again.

Comment: I guess we have a misunderstanding here. There are three projects on the spreadsheet and I want to get rid of two of them. So I want to remove a project from the spreadsheet and not a *.gs from a project.